# In mgcv, why can't a model fit large coefficients for each of the basis functions to play the role of an intercept?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, splines, mgcv

Let $$X \sim Unif(0,1000) \\ Y \sim N(1000, 1)$$

$X$ has no effect on $Y$, but for some reason, we decide to predict $y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon_i$ using a penalised B-spline (note the lack of intercept term).

After seeing how the basis function looks like:

```
# Create a smooth term matrix from the basis function
n_points <- 1e3
sm <- smoothCon(s(x,bs = "bs", k=10),
                data = data.frame(x = seq(0,n_points, by = 1)),
                knots=NULL)[[1]]
# Plot it with knots
matplot(sm$X, 
        type = 'l',
        xlim = range(sm$knots),
        xlab = "x", ylab = "B(x)")
abline(v  = sm$knots)
```

[image: B-Spline basis for X]

it seems reasonable to assume, the model could fit a large coefficient $\hat{\beta}$ to each basis, thus creating the equivalent of an intercept term and a zero coefficient for $X$.

```
# Show that it can fulfill the same role as an intercept
beta <- matrix(1000, ncol = 1, nrow = ncol(sm$X))
plot(sm$X %*% beta, type = "l", xlab = "X", ylab = "f hat of X")
```

[image: f aht of X]

However, that's not what we see when we fit the model in mgcv:

```
model <- gam(
  y~0 + s(x, bs = "bs", k = 10),
  method = "REML", 
  data = data.frame(
    y = rnorm(1000, mean = 1000, sd = 1), 
    x = runif(1000))
)
plot(model)
```

[image]

What is the underlying reason of this behaviour?

Comment: For identifiability¸ the smooth terms must sum to zero over the covariates (says Simon, author of the package): https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-October/337713.html . You'd normally standardize $x$ and $y$ anyway, so your example is a bit contrived

Comment: @BenA, thanks for your reply! This link is exactly what I was looking for!